# Facebook Login Button crashing app without error message

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

This issue suddenly popped up this morning after working great for weeks.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d("Facebook Login Status", "success!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("Facebook Login Status", "Canceled!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Log.d("Facebook Login Status", "Failed!");
        }


    });

}
```

Somewhere in there, the app crashes. None of the callback methods are run, and nothing is printed to logcat. I just see a loading spinner for a split second and then the app force closes with no message.

Edit:

I did find this log actually, but I don't know what it means.

```
04-24 15:44:56.787 1753-1753/com.android.systemui W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
04-24 15:44:56.788 1753-1753/com.android.systemui W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.devon_dickson.apps.oncampus: Resource ID #0x0
```

Comment: kindly accept the answer below it is the right answer.

Answer (score 9):

The same was happening to me, so I started from scratch with another Activity and slowly duplicated the new activity till it matched the one that was breaking. In short, it was nothing to do with the Activity but the Android Manifest.

In my Android Manifest, I had `android:noHistory="true"` on my LoginActivity which was crashing my app. Once I removed it then it worked again.

Comment: Woah. That worked. It was really difficult to debug without any logs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: it worked for me , thanks a lot. I was not able to find the issue but this solution really worked. thanks once again

Comment: Yes , works ! It is not difficult to write a log about it for Facebook. Years and years are flowing like water, and this sdk never surprise me !