# Android app crashes when "Continue with Facebook" pressed

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am implementing Facebook authentication for my android application and the app crashes straight away when I use to press "Continue with Facebook".

1. No invalid hash key error, I am sure my hash key is correct because when I put the wrong key it gives the invalid hash key error.
2. No errors and exceptions, There are no exceptions in Logcat. Facebook SDK is also not firing onError or onCancel events

I don't know how to debug it and also I didn't found any solution so far.

Comment: No exception in Logcat? I don't believe it. Check if you have set any filter or wrong app is selected in Logcat window.

Comment: Yes, there were no any exceptions. Found similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39368284/3701429 also found the solution in the same thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39368284/3701429

The problem was with this android:noHistory="true" attribute in my login activity in manifest.xml file.

After removing this attribute it is working fine.